# Kotlin constructor reference with generics

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have this code in (Rx)Java:

```
Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
    .flatMap(this::intToBooleanObservable, Pair::new)
    .....
```

I would expect to corresponding Kotlin code to look like:

```
Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
    .flatMap(::intToBooleanObservable, ::Pair)
    .....
```

However the compiler cannot infer the generic type of Pair, so the best I can do right now is:

```
.flatMap(::intToBooleanObservable, { a, b -> a to b })
```

Which isn't as concise as I would like it to be.

Is there a way to achieve this without declaring the variables `a` and `b`?

Comment: Just a side note, if your code after that flatMap is a mess, you'd probably end up with the same error message (can't infer type). If you fixed that mess then the type will be inferred correctly, without having to specify type info explicitly.

Comment: @glee8e the code after flatMap is `.subscribe { println(it) }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same trouble here. A few other workarounds (in the order I used them), you may like one of those.

1) Writing your own operator:

```
fun <T, U> Single<T>.flatMapPair(func: (T) -> Single<U>) : Single<Pair<T, U>> {
    return this.flatMap { t -> func.invoke(t).map { u -> t to u } }
}
```

2) Move the wrapping to the conditional Observable (here intToBooleanObservable), returning the result as a Pair or a more explicit and custom type (sealed class with 2 childs, like Success and Failure). This enable more explicit code :

```
 when(it) {
   is Success -> ...
   is Failure -> ...
}
```

3) Depending on intToBooleanObservable result you have now 2 different scenario (I imagine). Usually one is a sort of failure/denial, quick to resolve. For this matter write a filter with side effect where the predicate is an Observable, thus avoiding the problem :

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.filterSingle(predicate: (T) -> Single<Boolean>, rejectionFunction: (T) -> Unit): Observable<T> = ... //filter with the given predicate, and call rejectionFunction if item doesn't pass
```

4) The last method work only with boolean result. What if I am interested by the reason behind failure/refusal to give a meaningful message ? For the sake of homogeneous code, I dropped this operator. Inspired by other functionals languages, I defined a Either type and defined generic Either+RxJava operators; mapRight, flatMapRight and more important dropLeft. dropLeft is like a generalization of filterSingle.

```
inline fun <L, R> Observable<Either<L, R>>.dropLeft(crossinline sideEffect: (L) -> Unit): Observable<R> = this.lift { downObserver ->
    object: Observer<Either<L, R>> {
        override fun onError(throwable: Throwable?) = downObserver.onError(throwable)

        override fun onSubscribe(disposable: Disposable?) = downObserver.onSubscribe(disposable)

        override fun onComplete() = downObserver.onComplete()

        override fun onNext(either: Either<L, R>) = when (either) {
            is Right -> downObserver.onNext(either.value)
            is Left -> sideEffect(either.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: Thanks! I really like the first trick and it does exactly what I needed.
Just as a side note, `Int` and `Boolean` were just examples, I'd usually want something like `Group` and `User` that could be solved by creating a `data class`, but I wanted to avoid doing that for a single use.